# Custom domain for path in my heroku app

Tags: heroku

I have a heroku app that runs on `myapp.herokuapp.com` and I have already added a custom domain in the form of `myapp.mydomain.com`. But now I need a custom domain for a specific path in my app and I couldn't figure out wether it is possible and how to do it.

I'd like to have `mypaht.mydomain.com` as a custom domain for `myapp.herokuapp.com/my/path` is this possible? And if yes, how can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without code changes.
The heroku router will point all requests to your app's process, without changing the path.

So the only way to serve a different content for a different domain is to have a condition in your app's source code which handles that.

Comment: Is there maybe a way to use something like a virtual host like on an apache web server?

Comment: What language is your application written on?

Comment: Clojure using compojure

Comment: Your app will then not use Apache by default. You could add a custom buildpack which does that. It's generally not a recommended practice though. Handling this in your app's router would be the best way.